# I need to read numbers from a text file and then store them in a matrix, but I keep getting a null pointer

Tags: c, pointers, fopen

I need to read numbers from a text file and then store them in a matrix. This is what I have got so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{   
    int MazeMatrix[64];     
    int i;   

    FILE *mazefile; //created a pointer named mazefile  
    mazefile = fopen("m5.txt","r");         
    if (mazefile == NULL)   
    {       
        printf("Didn't work");          
    } 
    for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) 
    {       
        fscanf_s(mazefile, "%d", &MazeMatrix[i]);   
    }       
    printf("%d", &MazeMatrix);   
}
```

It builds but then I get the error `stream!=nullptr`.

Comment: In the test if the file failed to open, you need to exit.

Comment: regarding: `printf("Didn't work");`  1) when the call to `fopen()` failed, the code must not continue,  2) error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`  3) when an error indication is received from a C library function, the text reason the system thinks the error occurred should be output to `stderr`.  Strongly suggest: `{ perror( "fopen failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) separate code blocks: `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` via a single blank line

Comment: regarding: `printf("%d", &MazeMatrix);`  in C, referencing the name of an array degrades to the address of the first byte of the array.  so this statement is treating the name of the array as a `**`  which is not correct (and probably the reason for the execution failure.

Comment: Give the exact output and error message. There are little inconsistencies in this code like the mix of `fopen` and `fscanf_s`, going on after a failed open, and printing a pointer with `%d`, but it should not give a runtime error when given correct input...

Answer (score 1):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. properly checks for and handles errors
4. corrects the access on the array
5. eliminates the 'magic' numbers
6. exits the read loop if internal array full or EOF encountered
7. properly ends each format string with '\n' so the text will be immediately output
8. properly references MazeMatrix[] in the call to `printf()`
9. removes the two extraneous 'back ticks' in the posted code

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MATRIX_SIZE 64


int main( void )
{
    int MazeMatrix[ MATRIX_SIZE ];
    int i = 0;    // initialized per @chux comment
    FILE *mazefile = fopen("m5.txt","r");
    if ( !mazefile )
    {
        perror( "fopen failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    while( i< MATRIX_SIZE &&  fscanf(mazefile, "%d", &MazeMatrix[i]) != 1 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "failed to read a matrix entry\n" );
        fclose( mazefile );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    printf( "%d\n", MazeMatrix[0] );
}
```

Comment: `while( i< MATRIX_SIZE` and "performs the desired functionality" is suspicious.  `i` is undefined.

Comment: @chux, I added the initialization of variable `i`.  Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to preface this post by answering your question directly:

> I need to read numbers from a text file and then store them in a matrix, but I keep getting a null pointer [It builds but then I get the error `stream != nullptr`].

There are several things that could be going wrong in the code you posted. Most likely, the file `m5.txt` doesn't actually exist in the directory you specified.

[As stated in the Microsoft CRT Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/security-features-in-the-crt), `fscanf_s` and associated functions provide additional security through error and parameter checking. Looking at your code, the file not existing, at least in the same directory (or even, by the name you specified in the code), seems to be the most likely culprit. Again, [from the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/parameter-validation):

> In Debug builds, the invalid parameter macro usually raises a failed assertion and a debugger breakpoint before the dispatch function is called.

This macro/assertion failure seems to be what results in your `stream != nullptr` error.

When you check the file pointer you've just tried to open, you're checking to make sure it's not `NULL`, which is great, but you don't correctly handle the error. As others have pointed out, you should exit if you can't open the input file. This should kind of make sense, since if the whole point of your application is to read data in and process it, and you fail when trying to read the data, the rest of the application is going to have a mighty hard time doing anything.

The following is my rewriting of your code as I would recommend you do it. It might seem like overkill (and it is, for this toy example), but the point here is to get used to seeing code in a larger, more robust context. It might take a little bit for your eyes to adjust to significantly more code, but do your best to persevere through it; I've done my best to explain my reasoning behind each design/implementation decision.

---

To begin with, I will note that a matrix is a **two**-dimensional `MxN` structure. Given that you declared your array as having 64 elements, I'm going to assume you were looking for help on using a square, eight by eight matrix.

To declare our matrix, we do the following. First, we define a constant `N` to represent the number of elements in a single row of our matrix. Since we're working with a square matrix (such that `M = N`), I don't declare a separate constant for `M`, I just use the single one.

```
#define N (8)
```

Then, we declare our matrix like this:

```
int matrix[N][N] = { 0 };
```

In your program, you declared `MazeMatrix[64]`, `int i`, and `FILE *mazefile` without immediately initializing them. This is still commonly done as a holdover from the days when compilers required that you declare all variables at the beginning of your functions. This is no longer the case, so I recommend that in the spirit of clean, clear, small code, you declare variables when they're needed and you initialize variables when you declare them. In the code above, we're zeroing out the entire matrix.

In your code, your next two lines are:

```
FILE *mazefile; //created a pointer named mazefile
mazefile = fopen("m5.txt", "r");
```

We know you created a pointer named `mazefile` because in the code right before that comment, *You created a pointer named mazefile*. Keep in mind that a) You should be initializing this file handle as soon as you declare it as previously discussed, and 2) comments are great, but only if they are necessary (and effective) for helping someone else understand your code. In this case, your comment, while well-intentioned, is really just superfluous code noise and can be safely removed.

Here is my implementation of your program. Note that while I excluded that function prototypes for brevity, I described the functions further down this post.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define DEFAULT_FILE ("m4.txt")

#define N (8)

// [Function prototypes excluded for brevity]


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char* inputFileName = getInputFileName(argc, argv);

    int matrix[N][N] = { 0 };

    PrintMatrix(matrix, "Original Matrix");

    FILE *inputFile = readFile(inputFileName);

    ReadMatrix(matrix, inputFile);
    PrintMatrix(matrix, inputFileName);
    PrintSeparator();

    CloseFile(&inputFile);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

You'll notice I included `argc` and `argv` in my version. It becomes a hassle to keep recompiling your program every time you want to read in a different file, and there's really no reason for it. `argc` is the "arguments count" and `argv` is the "argument vector." `argc` will always be at least 1 because the name of the program is the first argument (and therefore `argv[0]` is always the name of your program).

In order to determine what file to open, we define a function `getInputFileName` like so:

```
const char* getInputFileName(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc == 2) {
        return argv[1];
    }

    return DEFAULT_FILE;
}
```

There are other ways to handle an empty argument to the program. You could simply just print an message to the console saying you must pass a parameter. I chose to simply define another macro to hold the name of a random file I made for ease during testing.

```
#define DEFAULT_FILE ("m4.txt")
```

***Note:** I generated my data sample files m1.txt through m8.txt with a simple random number generator program. I will include the code for that at the bottom of this answer in case it helps.*

Having allocated our matrix and determined our input file, we now print the matrix as-is, to verify that it has been indeed zeroed out.

```
void PrintMatrix(int m[][N], const char* name) {
    PrintSeparator();
    PrintMatrixName(name);
    PrintMatrixElements(m);
    printf("\n\n\n");
}
```

This function simply calls three other functions I wrote. This could have been much simpler, but this serves two purposes: first, you can see a simple implementation of abstraction, where we reduce the problem down into smaller and smaller bytes, and we deal with only the necessary complexity at a time. Second, I pretty-fied the output so it would look better, just for kicks.

Here are the three other functions: `PrintSeparator` just prints a horizontal line of `=` symbols of width 80. [Check out this question on Software Engineering Stack Overflow](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148677/why-is-80-characters-the-standard-limit-for-code-width) on why 80 is generally the standard. As [some code style advocates claim](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oyyFKHpzL0Q), humans read best with a 60-80 column screen, and I tend to agree, so I hard-coded it here, half-hoping it will lead to conformance by the masses, but you're welcome to change it. Again, it's just for pretty-fying the output, it's essentially meaningless.

```
void PrintSeparator(void) {
    printf("\n\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++) {
        putchar('=');
    }

    printf("\n\n");
}
```

This function simply prints the passed-in string. The deluge of format specifiers is for centering the name to the matrix. This is specific to an 8x8 matrix with this particular spacing, but if you modified the program to accept multiple files through `argv`, this function would allow you to print a unique name for each output matrix, say for example if you used the file name as the matrix name.

```
void PrintMatrixName(const char* name) {
    printf("\n\n\t\t\t\t%s\n\n", name);
}
```

This function, `PrintMatrixElements`, is really the main function for printing the matrix. In the `printf` format specification, I set an element width of two, since my data used random numbers from 1 to 10, and two blank spaces for readability. The outer loop also prints extra space so the matrix doesn't look too wide. This helps a lot with readability, in my opinion.

```
void PrintMatrixElements(m) {
    printf("\n\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("\t\t\t");

        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            printf("%2d  ", m[i][j]);
        }

        printf("\n\n");
    }

    printf("\n\n");
}
```

The next line in the program is especially significant:

```
FILE *inputFile = readFile(inputFileName);
```

Normally, you would simply declare a file pointer and initialize it by calling `fopen`, like this:

```
FILE *inputFile = fopen(inputFileName);
```

Like I said previously though, you really want to work within the same level of abstraction in the same function, so the error checking required doesn't really jive with the flow we want in main. That's why I defined an auxiliary function `openFile` that also returns a file pointer. This way, we can also use it to initialize a file pointer, the same way we use `fopen`, with the added bonus of built-in error checking.

```
FILE* openFile(const char* filename, const char* mode) {
    FILE *newFileHandle = fopen(filename, mode);

    if (!newFileHandle) {
        perror("Failed to open input file");

        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return newFileHandle;
}
```

Now, we can simply declare a file pointer like this:

```
FILE *inputFile = openFile("file.txt", "r");
```

However, if we're flat out naming our file pointer `inputFile`, clearly we're only reading from the file. That's why I declared a second auxiliary function `readFile`. Note that I didn't simply rewrite `openFile` and hard-code the `"r"` mode specifier. You should always try not to repeat yourself. That's why I simply defined this new function in terms of our previous function, `openFile`, like this:

```
FILE* readFile(const char* filename) {
    FILE *newFileHandle = openFile(filename, "r");

    return newFileHandle;
}
```

And then we declare our input file with this new function:

```
FILE *inputFile = readFile("file.txt");
```

While this may seem redundant at first, there are a few reasons why this isn't as crazy as it seems. [If you name your functions well] this helps add clarity to the code. It makes sense that an input file pointer would read an existing file, right? And since we've done all of our error checking in `openFile`, we don't have to worry about that in `readFile`. *Abstraction.*

Also, as Uncle Bob says,

> [functions should only do one thing.](https://medium.com/mindorks/how-to-write-clean-code-lessons-learnt-from-the-clean-code-robert-c-martin-9ffc7aef870c)

(He also says [to stick to one level of abstraction per function](http://principles-wiki.net/principles:single_level_of_abstraction), as we've done here.)

The next function is the real meat and potatoes of the program, because it is the function that is going to use the given input file to populate our matrix. Here is the code for `ReadMatrix`:

```
void ReadMatrix(int m[N][N], FILE *inputFile) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            int n = fscanf(inputFile, "%d", &m[i][j]);

            if (n == EOF) {
                fprintf(stderr, "\n\n<Premature END OF FILE encountered - not enough elements in input file! [N: %d | Required: %d]>\n\n", (i * N) + j, N * N);

                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            } else if (n == 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "\n\n<Error - incompatible data type in input file at line %d>\n\n", (i * N) + j + 1);

                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's important to note that this function assumes your input files are structured as simple numbers separated by new lines, like so:

```
7
12
56
8
4
66
```

This is how the function is written. Also, note that we could use `for` loops rather than having to resort to a `while` loop because we are setting the size of the matrix as a macro (in this case both the rows and the columns) with `N`, which in this case I've defined as 8. Since the size of the matrix is known to us at compile time, `for` loops will do the job fine. If you wanted to let the user determine the matrix size at run time, you would need to dynamically allocate the matrix and use `while` loops to populate it. ([Do not use variable-length arrays](http://www.reidatcheson.com/c/programming/2015/12/07/vlas.html))

There are a few more things to note about the `ReadMatrix` function. First, we're calling `fscanf` and setting a local variable `n` to its return value. We then check `n` for two possible errors:

First, if `fscanf` completely fails before it can even try to format it's input value (i.e... it gets EOF before reading all the values), it will raise an error. This is why our error message says "Premature end of file encountered," that's essentially what this is. It also includes a handy info message letting you know how many values it read in before it crashed, as well as how many values it's expecting.

Say for example, one of your input files, `m4.txt`, had only 4 elements:

```
7
11
84
9
```

Our error checking would then yield the following error message:

```
<Premature END OF FILE encountered - not enough elements in input file! [N: 4 | Required: 64]>
```

Second, We're checking `n` to make sure it's not zero. If everything goes well, `scanf`, `printf`, and co. return an integer value equal to "the number of [...] items assigned." [Source: [The Standard C Library, by P.J. Plauger](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131315099)] Hence, if `scanf` is returning 0, we've got a problem.

An example of this would be for example, if say in one of your input files, you had `kk` instead of a number on line 17. Our error checking implementation would result in the following message:

```
<Error - incompatible data type in input file at line 17>
```

Lastly, if either error occurs, we immediately call `exit` and pass it a return code of `EXIT_FAILURE`. This is simply a macro defined in `<stdlib.h>`, along with `EXIT_SUCCESS`, with the values:

```
EXIT_SUCCESS: 0
EXIT_FAILURE: 1
```

We will use this fact in our last function: `CloseFile`. First, the obvious question: *Why are we defining **another** function to close a file when there is already one defined in the standard?*

This is a valid question, and it again has to do with the concept of abstraction. It's not super widely known that `fclose` actually returns an integer value depending on whether it succeeds or fails (yes, it *can* fail), and so we again want to move the error checking to a different level of abstraction. Thus, we hereby define our `CloseFile` function:

```
void CloseFile(FILE **fileHandle) {
    if (fclose(*fileHandle)) {
        perror("Error Closing Input File");

        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Notice that we're passing our file pointer by reference here, using a double pointer. I did this for two reasons: first, pedagogically, it's important to remember how to pass pointers by reference; second, should you want to implement [Professor Reese's pointer heuristic here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449344186), you would need to pass in the pointer by reference anyways. Note that you'll need to use the "address-of" operator when you call the `CloseFile` function.

---

I know I probably hit you with a tsunami of information, but learning C is kind of like that. C is deceivingly simple, but starting to learn it can be tricky. Please do not hesitate to ask me any questions, good luck.

---

#### Generating Random Test Data

You did not include a sample data set, so to generate my datasets, I assumed a single number per line and 64 numbers per file (except on files where I was testing error handling). Note that this program does not have the safeguards from the last one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define N (8)


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: generate <file-name-1>");

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    srand(time(NULL));

    FILE *outputFile = fopen(argv[1], "w");

    if (!outputFile) {
        perror("Failed to open output file");

        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            fprintf(outputFile, "%d\n", rand() % 10 + 1);
        }
    }

    fclose(outputFile);

    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```